# Unable to emit assembly

Tags: vb.net, infopath-2007, vsta

I have created a visual basic class library named dataLibrary and have added it as a reference in a visual studio tools for application program in infopath 2007, and imported it.

Now when I try using a class defined in the library, I get the following error:
"Unable to emit assembly: Referenced assembly 'dataLibrary' does not have a strong name"

Can somebody help me out here, I've never seen anything like this before.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are likely encountering is that your class library has not been signed with a strong name, however your assembly *IS* signed.

**Resolution:**
*Either don't sign your assembly and leave the class library unsigned or sign both the assembly and class library.*

For more info, take a look at this solid answer on the topic:

[Why would I see "Unable to emit assembly: Referenced assembly ... does not have a strong name" when trying to add a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205639/why-would-i-see-unable-to-emit-assembly-referenced-assembly-does-not-have)